# How to implement a generic extension method for a Task with a generic type argument that's an interface

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, async-await, task

I'm trying to create an extension method for a `Task` with `IEnumerable<T>` as type argument that will return an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`. The reason I want this is to satisfy an interface. I experimented with it but I keep getting errors

My question: is it possible to have an extensions method like my first example that works for implementations of the type argument of the `Task` without having to specify the type arguments for the extension method?

Here is the extension method I created:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> GetAsyncEnumerable<T, TEnumerable>(this Task<TEnumerable> task) where TEnumerable : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        foreach (var item in await task)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles succesfully. The problem with it is that I cannot call it on a implementation of `IEnumerable` like `ICollection<T>` or `List<T>` like this:

```
var enumerable = Task.FromResult(new List<int>()).GetAsyncEnumerable();
```

It will throw this error:

```
The type arguments for method 'IAsyncEnumerable<T> Demo.EnumerableExtensions.GetAsyncEnumerable<T,TEnumerable>(this Task<TEnumerable>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

When I specify the type arguments it does compile: `var enumerable = Task.FromResult(new List<int>()).GetAsyncEnumerable<int, List<int>>();`

I also tried this variant but that also doesn't work:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> GetAsyncEnumerable<T>(this Task<IEnumerable<T>> task)
    {
        foreach (var item in await task)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

It throws this error:

```
The type arguments for method 'IAsyncEnumerable<T> Demo.EnumerableExtensions.GetAsyncEnumerable<T>(this Task<IEnumerable<T>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

Comment: Ouch. Yes, the compiler can't infer the type of `T` given just `TEnumerable`, you can't specify only some generic type arguments, and you do need `Task<TEnumberable>` as `Task<T>` isn't covariant

Comment: One option is to await the Task outside of the method, e.g. using `System.Linq.Async`'s `ToAsyncEnumerable`, and doing `(await task).ToAsyncEnumerable()`. Slightly more wordy, but at least you don't have to specife the generic type arguments.

Comment: @canton7 Yes that's possible. The "problem" with it is that the method would still be `async` without using `await`, or else it cannot return an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`. My IDE will warn about it but removing `async` will throw a compile error.

Comment: I'm afraid until [partial type inference](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1349) is not implemented there is not much you can do except the the solution by @canton7.